# CheckBox values in ListView wont change

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I think this is a known situation but I wont like to know **WHY** this happens.

I have a `ListView` with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and every item in it is a `RelativeLayout` which contains a `CheckBox` and a couple of `TextView`s.

When I click each checkbox I get a little blue "V" as expected, yet when my code iterates over all the items in the `ListView` and checks the status of thier checkboxs it says the all of them are false even though some of them are checked:

1. Why is that happening?
2. I saw that the solution is to store the values yourself and update them with a listener but all the posts I have seen about this issue are fairly old, is there currently a more elegant solution?

Thank You!

**EDIT:**
I dont have code to add currently since its not on this computer.

This is basically how I locate the checkbox:

```
*Loop header, the loop goes from 0 to adapter.getCount()-1*
View temp = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
CheckBox c = (CheckBox) temp.findViewByID(R.id.myBox);
if (c.isChecked()) ...
```

Comment: don't call `getView` yourself. adapters are recycling views, and what you are getting here is not what is going to be displayed. You need to either use the list ChoiceMode, or to set the checkbox in your custom adapter.

Comment: to further explain : the listview will only require the adapter to create the views for the visible items (typically < 10). This allows good performance on thousands of entries. What you are doing here is forcing the adapter to create all the views for all the entries. Moreover, since the recycling is done by the listview and not by the adapter, the views you create are basically discarded and never used.

Comment: So basically if I set choice mode I will be able to check one or multiple checkboxs and thier values should be changed? (when i'll check with isChecked)? if so how can I go over only the checked ones so I wont load the entire DB like you said? basically I want something to be performed only on the checked items

Comment: with `setChoiceMode`, you'll have to later use `getCheckedItem*` methods. However, that require that your item layout implements checkable. See https://developer.android.com/samples/CustomChoiceList/src/com.example.android.customchoicelist/CheckableLinearLayout.html for example

Comment: Thanks for the link but if I create the layout in java how will I add buttons to it? I only know how to do it through xml....

Comment: Also, it seems it keeps track of "checking" it but ithas no checkbox so I cant display the state of the check to the user..

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html if you go this way.